# Problem sending FormData file form data using React and Express

Tags: javascript, form-data

I have a problem that form data does not work for me
I used both versions of form data from npm which are present in the original

```
export const addNewProduct = createAsyncThunk('product/addNewProduct', async (args) => {
    const imgesCashingUrl = `${consts.server_url}collection/addProductImgs`;
    const FormData = new formData();
    FormData.append('imgs' , args.imgs); 
/*
args.imgs is data that contains information coming from the input file in the form, and I save it in react state after I add to each image its own blob URL for frontend purposes.

I also made sure that args.imgs is not empty and already contains data
*/

    const response = await axios.post(imgesCashingUrl, FormData,{
        'accept': 'application/json,*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${FormData._boundary}`,
    });
    return response;
});
```

args.imgs is data that contains information coming from the input file in the form, and I save it in react state after I add to each image its own blob URL for frontend purposes.

I also made sure that args.imgs is not empty and already contains data

I use Express as a server to receive files, and I also verified its currency by using post man

I tried postman and confirmed that the server is working fine
I also noticed that form data works when I change the data I add from files to text or digital data

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a syntax error. The correct declaration for `FormData` should be:

```js
const FormData = new FormData();
```

The reason for this correction is that JavaScript is case-sensitive, and the constructor for the `FormData` object must begin with an uppercase `F` as shown above. Using lowercase `formData` would result in an error because it's not the correct reference to the `FormData` object.

Consider using a more conventional variable name like data instead of FormData to make your code clearer and readable.

Comment: True, but in this case I used the form Data that I called after downloading it from npm
I called the library above the file as follows:
import formData from 'form-data'